# How to show two Plotly charts side-by-side in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

I want to have two Plotly charts appear next to one another on the same line. Presently one chart appears above the other.

[image: current]

This is my JavaScript code for the two graphs:

```
    var barData = [
    {
        x: x_names,
        y: y_data,
        text: y_names,
        marker: { color: 'rgba(202,210,211,.90)' },
        type: 'bar',
        orientation: 'v',
        width: 0.8,
        options: { offset: true }
    }];

var barLayout = {
    title: "<b>Arrears Balance Managed by CSM</b>",
    showlegend: false,
    xaxis: { tickangle: 45, zeroline: true },
    yaxis: { gridwidth: 1, zeroline: true },
    height: 400,
    width: 500,

};

Plotly.newPlot('bar', barData, barLayout);

var donutData = [{
    labels: y1_names,
    values: x1_data,
    hole: .4,
    type: "pie"
}];

var donutLayout = {
    height: 400,
    width: 500,
    margin: {"t": 0, "b": 0, "l": 0, "r": 0},
    showlegend: true
    }

Plotly.newPlot('pie', donutData, donutLayout);
```

The following is from my html document:

```
  <h3 class='display-4'>Graphs</h3>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="bar">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="pie">
  </div>
```

Is there a way to get the two charts to line up next to one another?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a modern browser with your web page. I suggest you use the following CSS: `display: flex;`. Here is a link to a good guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You can also see the example I made in the code snippet:

```css
.graph-container {
  display: flex;
}

#bar {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

#pie {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<h3 class='display-4'>Graphs</h3>
<div class='graph-container'>
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="pie"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is a very good answer, It works. Just a heads up, for it to work completely, in each of the CSS rules for pie and bar do `flex:1;`